# Problems with conditional dictionary lookup via if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary

I have a dictionary which I am populating with values. The values are served to the dictionary through a for-loop.

```
storageDict = {}
listholder = ["word1", "word2", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5", "word6", "word7"]
values = ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word2", "word5", "word6", "word7", "word8"]
index_tracker = 0

for each_element in listholder:
    if index_tracker == 7:
        pass
    else:
        storageDict[str(each_element)] = values[index_tracker]
        index_tracker += 1

print(storageDict)
```

This gives me the following output:

```
 {'word5': 'word6', 'word1': 'word1', 'word3': 'word2', 'word4': 'word5', 'word6': 'word7', 'word2': 'word3'}
```

While all key-value combinations are unique I would like to avoid any scenarios whereby the dictionary contains a key-value combination that is the same as the value-key combination. i.e In the dictionary above we have the following two key-value combinations:

- `'word3': 'word2'`
- `'word2': 'word3'`

I would therefore like to check whether a value-key combination and key-value combination is already in the dictionary before committing it to the dict. I came up with the following code, but PyCharm is giving me a `KeyError`:

```
storageDict = {}
listholder = ["word1", "word2", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5", "word6", "word7"]
values = ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word2", "word5", "word6", "word7", "word8"]
index_tracker = 0

for each_element in listholder:
    if index_tracker == 7:
        pass
    else:
        if storageDict[each_element] == values[index_tracker] and storageDict[values[index_tracker]] == each_element:
             pass
        else:
            storageDict[each_element] = values[index_tracker]
            index_tracker += 1

print(storageDict)
```

My desired output is one for the two scenarios:

```
    {'word5': 'word6', 'word1': 'word1', 'word4': 'word5', 'word6': 'word7', 'word2': 'word3'}
```

or:

```
    {'word5': 'word6', 'word1': 'word1', 'word3': 'word2', 'word4': 'word5', 'word6': 'word7'}
```

Here's the `KeyError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/momely/placementarchitect/testbench.py", line 42, in <module>
if storageDict[each_element] == values[index_tracker] and storageDict[values[index_tracker]] == each_element:
KeyError: 'word1'
```

I believe I understand why the error occurs. By including my check in the conditional if statement I am requesting the key-value for a dictionary key that doesn't exist yet.

But how would anyone check a key-value then?

I considered working with tuples instead but will require the dictionary's fast loopup in a different operation.

Comment: Actually what is your expecting output ?

Comment: Hi there. My desired output is this: {'word5': 'word6', 'word1': 'word1', 'word3': 'word2', 'word4': 'word5', 'word6': 'word7'}. Will add above.

Comment: You can check that `item in some_dict` => `True` if `some_dict` has `item` as a key. Or you can just handle the `KeyError` exception. Or you can use the `dict.get` method, `some_dict.get(item)` will return the value if there is such a key, or  ̀None` if there is not.

Comment: [```dict.get```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) is made for this.

Comment: Hi there. That is one part of the solution. But this won't solve my problem exactly. If I used some_dict.get(item) in the if statement instead (if storageDict.get(each_element) == values[index_tracker] and storageDict.get(values[index_tracker]) == each_element:). I get the same output: {'word2': 'word3', 'word5': 'word6', 'word6': 'word7', 'word3': 'word2', 'word4': 'word5', 'word1': 'word1'}. Here the combinations 'word2': 'word3', and 'word3': 'word2' are still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. I basically [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) them, filter the entries we don't need and then convert the filtered list into [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict).

```
listholder = ["word1", "word2", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5", "word6", "word7"]
values = ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word2", "word5", "word6", "word7", "word8"]
filtered = []
allItems = zip(listholder, values)
for key, value in allItems:
    if not ( (key,value) in filtered or (value, key) in filtered):
        filtered.append((key,value))
print dict(filtered)
```

Output:

```
{'word5': 'word6', 'word4': 'word5', 'word7': 'word8', 'word6': 'word7', 'word1': 'word1', 'word2': 'word3'}
```

Answer (score 0):

**RESPONSE INACCURATE**

Ok. With the help of @spectras and @wwii (thank you for pointing me in the right direction) I was able to come up with a solution. The issue was in the way I set up my logical check in combination with not using the some_dict.get(item) method.

Here the solution:

```
storageDict = {}
listholder = ["word1", "word2", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5", "word6", "word7"]
values = ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word2", "word5", "word6", "word7", "word8"]
index_tracker = 0

for each_element in listholder:
    if index_tracker == 7:
        pass
    else:
        if storageDict.get(each_element) == storageDict.get(values[index_tracker]) and each_element == storageDict.get(values[index_tracker]):
            pass
        else:
            storageDict[each_element] = values[index_tracker]
        index_tracker += 1

print(storageDict)
```

This generates the output as desired:

```
{'word5': 'word2', 'word7': 'word6', 'word6': 'word5', 'word2': 'word1', 'word3': 'word2', 'word4': 'word3'}
```

Thank you everyone for your useful tips. This really helped me resolve this.

M

Comment: The entry  'word1': 'word1' is missing in this. From your comment below the question it seems you wanted that?

Comment: Oh yeah! You are right! NOW i need to down-vote my own response! LOL! Thank you for picking that up!

Comment: No problem. There are multiple ways to solve this. I posted one such way.

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` on both list and check if a key-value pair has an alternate value-key pair in the dictionary:

```
d = {}

for k, v in list(zip(listholder, values))[:-1]:
    if v in d:
        if d[v] == k:
            continue
    d[k] = v

print(d)
# {'word5': 'word6', 'word4': 'word5', 'word2': 'word3', 'word1': 'word1', 'word6': 'word7'}
```

Existing keys get updated in your original code, and you're skipping the last items in both lists. I have replicated those here.